# Send email input to popout window

Tags: javascript, html

I have made this code and script for [my blog](http://www.thingsthatmademe.com) - it's for the contact page, and I have one problem. I would like to send the email provided to the popup windows, so that the user doesn't have to re-enter it. But can't seem to get it to work. I've added an event to the submit-button, because the code is just intended for a contact form, (it's a blogger code, and I don't have access to the script.)

HTML:

```
<form name="contact-form">Hvad skal jeg kalde dig?
<br />
<input class="contact-form-name" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-name" name="name" placeholder="Skriv dit navn her ..." size="40" style="margin-top: 10px;" type="text" value="" />
<br />
<br />Hvordan svarer jeg dig? <span id="required">*</span>

<br />
<input class="contact-form-email" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email" name="email" placeholder="Indtast din email her ..." size="40" style="margin-top: 10px;" type="text" value="" />
<br />
<br />Hvad vil du gerne fortælle mig?<span id="required">*</span>

<br />
<textarea class="contact-form-email-message" cols="25" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="email-message" placeholder="Skriv din besked til mig her ..." rows="8" style="margin-top: 10px;"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="nyhedsbrev">Tilmeld dig mit nyhedsbrev</p>
<input name='uri' type='hidden' value='ThingsThatMadeMe' />
<input name='loc' type='hidden' value='en_US' />
<input class="contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit2" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-submit" size="40" type="button" value="Send din besked" onclick="myFunction()">
<br />
<br />
<div class="contact-form-error-message" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message"></div>
<div class="contact-form-success-message" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message"></div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("ContactForm1_contact-form-submit").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

    if (document.getElementById('nyhedsbrev').checked) window.open("https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=ThingsThatMadeMe", "popupwindow", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes,width=550, height=520 method=post action=https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?");
}
</script>
```

This code in general is working fine. It's just this one thing, that's bugging me.

Comment: Your function is not being executed because simply its not being called. Simply said, the function you have put up right there is not being called, because you dont tell it to. Your first statement, in the script is simply, you bing a click event to it, but there is no code within the click event. Your file is techincally a lose function with no input and an event with no code to run in

Comment: Are you using JS code before closing body tag `</body>`, if not, try after moving your code before `</body>`

Comment: The script is working. And it's getting called. That is not the question :-)

I simply want to transfer the email input to the pop-up window, and I don't know how to do this. What code do I use? Is it in the script? Or in the HTML I have to change something?

Comment: Do you have acccess to the page that the pop up window is displaying? And, how has that page being rendered? is it php? .asp? Anyhoo, what it can be done is to add the email via url: "feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=ThingsThatMadeMe&email=" + document.email.value. Then, in the target page, populate the input text with the passed value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm totally new to all this, so I'm not quite sure, what you mean :-) It's a Feedburner/google page. Do I just change the 'windowOpen' link with the link you provided?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you are not able of manipulating the code of the target page, you won't be able to use this method either. I thought that will be the case considering the target page is a google page and that's why I wrote this as a comment instead of as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move your JS code before closing BODY tag i.e. before `</body>` or after your FORM code.

You can check working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7j8s0wen/2/

Comment: The script is working. And it's getting called. That is not the question :-)

I simply want to transfer the email input to the pop-up window, and I don't know how to do this. What code do I use? Is it in the script? Or in the HTML I have to change something?